# Dica de VBA Macro - Seleção de conteúdo variável

Tags: vba, excel-vba, macro

Estou fazendo uma macro simples, mas não estou conseguindo. Quero que a macro localize o valor de uma célula específica, que esse valor fique variando enquanto a macro que está gerando:

```
Sub teste()
    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells.Find(What:="36   ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

Aqui ele fica travado sempre procurando o 36, mas quero que procure o valor que estiver em "C1".

Answer (score 1):

Crie variáveis durante a execução do código. A variável permite que você referencie um valor/conteúdo para ela e reaproveite esse valor/conteúdo ao longo do código de execução da macro.

No exemplo foi criada a variável `conteudoVariavel` (pode usar outro nome que preferir) e ele é utilizado no parâmetro "What" da "Find". Adapte e teste conforme a sua necessidade específica.

Código com comentários, para melhor entendimento.

```
Sub teste()
    Dim conteudoVariavel As Variant 'declara a variável para a macro
    conteudoVariavel = Range("C1") 'coloca o valor de C1 na variável criada
    
    'agora pode utilizar a variável "conteudoVariavel" em qualque lugar que precisar
    Cells.Find(What:=conteudoVariavel, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```